# secure php session handling that uses mysql storage

Tags: php, mysql, security, session

I’m trying to find a lightweight PHP session handling library, i’ve googled and fallen into confusion.

1. I want a library that stores sessions using MySQL
2. allows kicking out of logged in user
3. does ip matching
4. browser matching
5. secure to session hacking etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you done so far? Please post your code.

Comment: ive been reading on zebra_sessions, havent yet implemented code.my old code uses default php sessions

Comment: Take a look at [phpSec](http://phpseclib.com), it has a custom session handler. But a whole library might be overkill for your needs..

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with MySQL and PHP it's rather trivial to write your own session handler.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php

It may be faster to write a personalized one than searching for exactly what you want.

Comment: was hoping there was a library.

Comment: What about the other four items?

Comment: "write your own" meant to suggest that all specific needs be hand-written.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at this [article by Chris Shiflett](http://shiflett.org/articles/storing-sessions-in-a-database), which describes making changes to session_set_save_handler().

Comment: What about the other four items?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out [this class that I made a while ago](http://pastebin.com/JZ7tuLb0)... it does everything that you say expect for kick a user out, but you can mae a function that does that in 5 minutes (just call the delete method with the user id that you want to kick out).

It still needs documentation and some tweeks here and there, but you can give yourself an idea of how is done.

**I wouldn't relay on user's IP for security, if they're using rotating IP (some cellphones companies) or they're behind thor or something you're going to have issues, use user_agent instead.**